# Android keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I have two keyboard installed- Swype and samsung. Is there any way I can force Android to show samsung keyboard on my EditText no matter what my setting is ??

Also is there a filter where I can disable text prediction??

Thank you.

Comment: You will likely have more luck here: http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set edittext widget's inputType for what you want like below

You can read more here

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html

There is a long list of available preferences here

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType